# Unique Items in a pandas dataframe with a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove all columns from a pandas dataframe where there are fewer than 10 unique items in the column. However, some of my data is lists and I get the error `unhashable type: 'list'`. Makes sense, since pandas compares with a hashmap.

My current code is

```
for i in df.columns:
    if len(df[i].unique()) < 10:
        df.drop(i, 1)
```

which works fine up until I get to a list object. For my purposes, a list1 and list2 aren't unique. `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` are not unique, even though `[1, 2] == [2, 1]` is False.

How should I go about performing this operation? It doesn't make sense to separate the lists, and I can't explicitly type out the columns since I have 1400 of them.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe here is a good place to use sets? `set([1,2]) == set([2,1])` is True

Comment: Side note, if you don't have to drop columns sequentially, you can just form a list of in-scope columns and drop them together after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list` objects are not hashable because they are mutable, but `tuple`, on the other hand, are immutable. You can `transform` list values to `tuple` and make use of this property.

Suppose you have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], 
                   "B": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                   "C": [[1,2,3], [2], [2,3,1], [4]] })

    A   B   C
0   1   a   [1, 2, 3]
1   2   b   [2]
2   3   c   [2, 3, 1]
3   4   d   [4]
```

Thus, you can do something like

```
df.C.apply(sorted).transform(tuple).unique()
```

which returns

```
array([(1, 2, 3), (2,), (4,)], dtype=object)
```

Thus, your code could be something like below, making use of `collections.Hashable` to check whether the content of the column is indeed hashable or not

```
import collections

for i in df.columns:
    if isinstance(df[i].iloc[0], collections.Hashable):
        if len(df[i].unique()) < 10: 
            df = df.drop(i, 1)
    else:
        if len(df[i].apply(sorted).transform(tuple).unique()) < 10: 
            df = df.drop(i, 1)
```

---

Notice that this would also apply to other unhashable types, such as `dict`s

```
>>> df["D"] = [{"a":2}, {}, {"k":3}, {"k":3}]})
>>> print(df.D.apply(sorted).transform(tuple).unique())
[('a',) () ('k',)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert the troublesome types to hashable alternatives. In the below example, there are 14 elements, but `[1, 2] == [2, 1]` after converting both sides to `frozenset` and, in addition, `0 == False`. So we calculate 12 unique values.

```
s = pd.Series([[1, 2], [2, 1], (1, 2, 3), {5, 1}, 3142, 563.123, np.nan, 'dfa',
               '', 'dsafa', 3214, 0, True, False])

print(len(s))  # 14

def converter(x):
    return frozenset(x) if isinstance(x, (set, list)) else x

print(len(s.apply(converter).unique()))  # 12
```